# Calculate Total Price in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a "Cart" component that displays the title, code, quantity, price of products!
I would like if someone could help calculate "price total" when I send various products into the cart!
My "Cart" component code (bare in mind that {cartProduct.price} is the price of one product but when I add more than one of this product to cart it updates the quantity, but not the Total Price)

```
class Cart extends Component {
   removeFromCart = (product) => {
    const cartProducts = this.props.cart 
    const updatedCartProducts = cartProducts.filter(item => item.id !== product.id);
  
  }

  render () {
    const cartProducts = this.props.cart
    return (
      <>
        <PanelHeader size="sm" />
        <div className="content">
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader>
                  <CardTitle tag="h4">Products List</CardTitle>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>#</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Code Item</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Price Total</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {cartProducts.map((cartProduct, index) => (             
                      <tr key={cartProduct.id}>
                    <th scope="row">{index +1}</th>
                    <td>{cartProduct.title}</td>
                    <td>{cartProduct.code}</td>
                    <td>{cartProduct.quantity}</td>
                    <td>{cartProduct.price}</td>
                    <td><button onClick ={() => this.props.removeCart(cartProduct)} className="btn btn-danger cart-button px-4">Remove</button></td>
                      </tr>))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state)=> {
  return {
      cart: state.cart
       }
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => { 
      return {
        removeCart: (product) => {dispatch(removeCart(product))}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

and my reducer file where I update the items quantity (I m not sure if its needed) is the following:

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from './constants'
import { REMOVE_FROM_CART } from './constants'
// import { ADD_QUANTITY} from './constants'
// import { SUB_QUANTITY}  from './constants'
// import { EMPTY_CART}  from './constants'


const initialState = {
    cart: [],
  }
const ShoppinReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:

      let newCart = [...state.cart]
      let itemIndex = state.cart.findIndex(obj => obj.id === action.payload.id)
      let currItem = state.cart[itemIndex]

      if (currItem) {
      currItem.quantity = parseInt(currItem.quantity) + 1
      state.cart[itemIndex] = currItem
      newCart = [...state.cart]

      }

      else {

      newCart = newCart.concat(action.payload)
      }

      return {
      cart: newCart
      }

    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      const cart = [...state.cart]
      const updatedCart = cart.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id)

      return {
        ...state,
        cart: updatedCart
      }
    
    default:
    return state
  }
}
  export default ShoppinReducer
```

I have an idea that I must create a function that will multiply quantity*price but not sure how to implement it!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't handle this will Redux, It would be better to calculate the values of the `cartItems` on your React component/page.

You can calculate the total price by looping through the cart, getting the price of each product and adding in each price to a single variable.

```
{cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.price, 0).toFixed(2)}
```

- toFixed() rounds the total price to 2 decimal places

This way you would not have to update the Redux store every time the user add/removes/updates the quantity of an item.

Comment: H. Yeap I wouldn't intend to use redux however I do not know where shall I put the code that you posted! Sorry for my ignorance, I am new in programming!

Comment: Are you calculating the total price of a users' cart?

Comment: H I calculate each product total price rendered on Cart UI ...i.e. quantity of each product added multiplied by the price of each product. Something like: 5jeans x 50$ = 250 $ Total...This is my idea

Comment: Then add the total to your Cart UI.

Example - `<span className="order-summary-values">Total ${cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.price, 0).toFixed(2)}</span>`

Comment: @ Karl H... I would like to display total on line 35 of my code where says 
<th scope="col"><strong>Price Total</strong></th> Bare in mind that I have on line 45 I have : <td>{cartProduct.price}</td>

Comment: That is up to you how you would like your UI to look & feel.

Comment: What you could @Shpongle is add another table column then calculate the subtotal of that row (so `cartProduct * cartQuantity` in the `map` function) and have another row after the map function to display the total of the cart products.

Comment: H I followed your last suggestion and created
<th scope="col"><strong>Sub Total</strong></th>  and inside the map function:
<td>{cartProduct.price * cartProduct.quantity}</td> but it displays "NaN" underneath the Sub Total...I am missing the functionality of price*quantity...The syntax must be wrong!

Comment: NaN means Not a Number so is `price` or `quantity` a string. You can't perform arithmetic calculations on Strings, you need to parse price/quantity to an Int. I suppose its your product quantity because you parsing it, to an int in your redux file.

Comment: H Yes that's the case...displays NaN because I have parsed it in my redux but do not know how to solve this issue! :(

Comment: Try `<td>{parseInt(cartProduct.quantity)}</td>`

Comment: <td>{parseInt(cartProduct.quantity)} Returns the quantity of the product! It gives a number however {parseInt(cartProduct.quantity*cartProduct.price} returns NaN again...Am I missing something in syntax!

Comment: Not that I can see, but I can't debug further, because I can't reproduce the problem. I would try though to declare a local variable in the map function and assign it  `{parseInt(cartProduct.quantity*cartProduct.price}` then just put that local variable in the subtotal row.

Comment: This is why parseInt is not working. Read these articles @Shpongle [parseInt in map](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-parseint-map/)  and [parseInt MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#tricky_use_case)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple function to calculate total:

```
const calculateTotal = () => {
    let total = 0;
    cart.map((item) => (total = total + item.quantity * item.price));
    return total;
  };
```

My UI code is a datatable:

```
<DataTable>
          <DataTable.Header theme={theme}>
            <DataTable.Title theme={theme}>Item</DataTable.Title>
            <DataTable.Title theme={theme} numeric>
              Count
            </DataTable.Title>
            <DataTable.Title theme={theme} numeric>
              Price
            </DataTable.Title>
          </DataTable.Header>
          {cart.map((item) => (
            <Pressable key={item.id}>
              <DataTable.Row>
                <DataTable.Cell>{item.name}</DataTable.Cell>
                <DataTable.Cell numeric>{item.quantity}</DataTable.Cell>
                <DataTable.Cell numeric>
                  {item.price * item.quantity}
                </DataTable.Cell>
              </DataTable.Row>
            </Pressable>
          ))}
          <DataTable.Row>
            <DataTable.Cell></DataTable.Cell>
            <DataTable.Cell>Total</DataTable.Cell>
            <DataTable.Cell numeric>{calculateTotal()}</DataTable.Cell>
          </DataTable.Row>
        </DataTable>
```

This is how it looks in my app. Don't mind the design and formatting as I am yet to apply themes and styles but this should give you an idea.

[Cart Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NULa.png)